# Setting default scroll point on <div>

Tags: css, html, scroll, scrollview

I have

```
.scroller {
    font-family : Arial,Sans-Serif;
    background : white;
    overflow-y : scroll;
    font-size  : 9.5pt; /* needed for scrollers w/o tables */
    }
```

Which i later apply to

```
<div class="scroller">
   ... lots of content here ...
</div>
```

By default the top portion of content in the scroller is shown. I want to slide to something in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your content is like this :

```
<div class="scroller">
   <div id="1">
      ... lots of content here ...
   </div>
   <div id="2">
      ... lots of content here ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Use this to scroll to `<div id="2">` :

```
$("div.scroller").scrollTop($("#2").offset().top);
```

Take a look an example here : [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dirgagautama/7CCDK/3/).